# Can I put pthread_barrier in shared memory to implement IPC?

Tags: c, pthreads, ipc, shared-memory

I want to implement IPC in C: put a barrier somewhere so that different processes can all start running from the barrier simultaneously.

I tried pthread_barrier along with shared memory. Process 1 allocates a piece of shared memory and initializes a pthread_barrier object there. Then, process 2 will attach this shared memory and use the barrier.

I run process 1 first. However, the output shows that process 2 performs correctly(arrive at the barrier where process 1 is already waiting and go forward), while process 1 will be hung up forever, seems like it is still waiting.

Here are the codes.

```
    // process 1
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    
        /* initialize a shared variable in shared memory */
        key_t shmkey = ftok("/dev/null", 5);
        printf("shmkey for barrier = %d\n", shmkey);
    
        int shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(pthread_barrier_t), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    
        if (shmid < 0)
        {
            perror("shmget\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        pthread_barrier_t* pBarrier = (pthread_barrier_t*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);     /* attach pBarrier to shared memory */
        pthread_barrier_init(pBarrier, NULL, 2);    /* barrier is initialized in shared memory, the number of waiting thread is 2 */
    
        std::cout << "kernel 1 is ready" << std::endl;
        pthread_barrier_wait(pBarrier);
        std::cout << "kernel 1 i going" << std::endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

```
// process 2
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* initialize a shared variable in shared memory */
    key_t shmkey = ftok("/dev/null", 5);
    printf("shmkey for barrier = %d\n", shmkey);

    int shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(pthread_barrier_t), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (shmid < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_barrier_t* pBarrier = (pthread_barrier_t*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);     /* attach pBarrier to shared memory */

    std::cout << "kernel 2 will sleep for 5 secondes" << std::endl;

    sleep(5);

    std::cout << "kernel 2 is ready" << std::endl;

    pthread_barrier_wait(pBarrier);
    std::cout << "kernel 2 is going" << std::endl;

    /* Clean the shared memory */
    // sleep(3);
    // shmdt(pBarrier);
    // shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

```
[output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEx91.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Process 2 can access this barrier object, it is not fully shared across processes. You need to assign proper attribute for that barrier.

```
    pthread_barrierattr_t barrier_attr;
    pthread_barrierattr_setpshared(&barrier_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    pthread_barrier_init(shared_barrier, &barrier_attr, 2);
```